# Add <br /> after 3rd symbol in Array

Tags: php

I have the following variable:

```
$checkbox = implode(';', $_POST['product']);
```

$checkbox is equal to "Product Name;Price;Unit", how can I add a break after every line?

At the moment $checkbox is equal to:

```
ASFP4040;18.95;1;ASFP4048;21;1;ASGS100100;25.45;1
```

I need it to be like:

```
ASFP4040;18.95;1;
ASFP4048;21;1;
ASGS100100;25.45;1;
```

EDIT:

I am writing this to a .TXT file, \n shows as text and doesn't actually create a new line.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you mean `implode(";<br/>", $_POST['product']);` :)

Comment: if you want to display in html 
implode(";<br/>", $_POST['product']);

Comment: What does your `$_POST['product']` look like?

Comment: @bassxzero - Depends on if he wants the like break to be displayed in HTML or printed in a file. Anyway, I just realized that it wasn't after each `;` he wants the break so we need to see the original array.

Comment: yap if he could do a print_r or vardump on that $_POST['product'] would be easier

Comment: If you add `\n`, it must be in double quotes `";\n"`. If you use single quotes, it will print out `\n` instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this worked but is it possible to remove the semi-colon from the end of each line?

Comment: @Dan Use `"\n"` instead of `";\n"` in your `implode`

Comment: @roberto06 I have now used ";\n" based on the above comment but I need to somehow remove the end semi-colon on lines 1 and 2... A semi-colon cannot exist on the end of a line.

Comment: Yep, that's why you have to use `"\n"` **without** the semicolon.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson put you answer as an answer so that he can tick it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm not sure, how your `$_POST['products']` var looks like, you might like one of these options:

**If you have everything in a single array element like this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASFP4040
    [1] => 18.95
    [2] => 1
    [3] => ASFP4048
    [4] => 21
    [5] => 1
    [6] => ASGS100100
    [7] => 25.45
    [8] => 1
)
```

you could split the array into chunks and join them together

```
$data = implode("\n", array_map(function($chunk) {
    return implode(';', $chunk);
}, array_chunk($_POST['product'], 3)));
```

---

**Alternatively, if you have an array of strings like below:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASFP4040;18.95;1
    [1] => ASFP4048;21;1
    [2] => ASGS100100;25.45;1
)
```

a simple implode would be enough

```
$data = implode("\n", $_POST['product']);
```

Comment: this $data = implode(";\n", $_POST['product']); works but if I have 3 products in my array, the 1st and second line ends with a semi-colon and the third does not. I somehow need to make each line end without a semi-colon?

Comment: just add a semicolon in the end?

Comment: I am trying to remove the END semi-colon, not add one.

Comment: For example, line 1 and 2 end with a semi-colon, line 3 does not. I need all lines to end without.

Comment: oh.. I see - changed again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo "'".implode("','",$checkbox)."'<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this. Just replace my `$str` with your `$checkbox`.

```
$str = 'ASFP4040;18.95;1;ASFP4048;21;1;ASGS100100;25.45;1';
$str2 = preg_replace('/((?:(?:[^;]+);){3})/',"$1\n",$str);
echo $str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Magnus Eriksson's comment and mine, you just have to use `"\n"` as first parameter of your `implode`:

```
$checkbox = implode("\n", $_POST['product']);
```

Please notice the use of double quotes (`"`) in order for `\n` to be used as a linebreak.